# Making SQL Server a Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a production database off site on another box which I reference by IP. Lets say its IP:

```
123.45.67.89
```

Now I want to do a query that references both my server here locally called MYSERVER1 with my production server.

When I try to do:

```
select count(*) from [MYSERVER1].MyDBName.dbo.mytable;
```

everything is fine. But I can't do this:

```
select count(*) from [123.45.67.89].MyDBName.dbo.mytable;
```

Is there a way to link the servers? Like using sp_addLinkedServer?

I get this error:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 3
>   Could not find server '123.45.67.89' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Any ideas? (I want to copy X number of rows to my production server, that's why)

Comment: Did you actually add the remote server to the linked servers of your local server?

Comment: You could start by looking at [the documentation for `sp_addlinkedserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) - you mention this in your question but yet you never looked it up?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Management Studio add your remote server: first connect to your local server, go to Server Objects\Linked Server in the Object Explorer and right click and add a new one.

BTW: you can also do it with system storedprocs, but it is something that you do only occasionally  I would stay with the GUI.

Comment: oh okay let me look at this then